# Navier-Cauchy-equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Why is the Navier-Cauchy equation (as given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity) a second order wave equation?
How can I proof this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to prove it. It is a matter of definition. The equation of motion involves a second derivative of displacement with respect to time. In that equation, the components of the stress tensor must be replaced by linear combinations of the components of the strain tensor, which are in turn expressed through partial derivatives of the displacement. The final outcome is a set of equations containing, on one side, the second partials of displacements w.r.t. time and, on the other, second partial derivatives with respect to spatial coordinates. Such equations describe wave propagation, just like the standard wave equation but the waves are more complex, like spherical waves for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer :)  The wave equation I am looking at is basically $u_{tt} = c^2(x)\Delta x$ and I thought, the term with the seond order partial derivatives in the Navier-Cauchy belongs to the Laplace-Operator in the above equation. How do the terms with the first partial derivatives in the Navier-Cauchy equation match to this wave equation? And how do I use c?

Comment: If you assume that your medium is homogeneous, that is the $C_{ijkl}$ are constant, I think you end up with a term $C^2\Delta u$ on the right hand side, $C$ being just a constant, related to the speed of wave propagation. However, in the non-homogeneous case you don’t get the simple structure $c^2(x,y,z)\Delta u$ but some extra first order terms (sort of drift). You can just try the simplest case, say $\sigma_{ij}=\epsilon_{ij}$ and collect the second order terms to see if it is a multiple of the Laplacian or not.